# apply a function to a parameter grid and return a list of lists in purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I often use lists of lists to apply a function (often a model call) onto a grid of parameters.

Here is an example with `paste` as the ultimate function:

```
library(tidyverse) #purrr
a=c("A", "B", "C") %>% set_names %>% map(function(x){
  c("m0", "m1") %>% set_names %>% map(function(y){
    c("absolute", "relative") %>% set_names %>% map(function(z){
      paste(x,y,z)
    })
  })
})
a$A$m0$absolute #exact expected output
```

I am looking for a way to get the exact same result with a simpler call, probably by using `cross` or `expand.grid` and `pmap` or `at_depth`.

I got something interesting with `pmap` + `expand.grid` but it flattened the structure and droped the names:

```
b=expand.grid(variable=c("A", "B", "C"), model=c("m0", "m1"), type=c("absolute", "relative")) 
a=b %>% pmap(~{paste(..1,..2,..3)}) #a simple list of length 12
```

In the best case, the function would even be able to use names (`variable, model, type`) inside the map call (instead of `..1,..2,..3` for `pmap`).

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: `variable %>% set_names %>% map(~ model) %>% map(set_names) %>% map_depth(2,~ type) %>% map_depth(2, set_names)` gets the structure you want but adding `map_depth(3, cross3(type, model, variable) %>% map(rev) %>% map(paste, collapse=" "))` doesn't work for unclear reasons

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you need to evaluate a function over a combination of parameters **and** save the result in a nested list structure defined by the combination of parameters hierarchically. Using a function with recursion, an approach is:

```
ff = function(args, FUN, init = list(), collect = list())
{
    if(!length(args)) return(as.call(c(FUN, collect))) 
    for(i in 1:length(args[[1]])) 
        init[[args[[1]][i]]] = ff(args[-1], FUN = FUN,
                                  collect = c(collect, setNames(list(args[[1]][i]), names(args)[1])))
    return(init)
}
```

The above function returns an unevaluated call (for the sake of the example; *in actual usage `do.call(FUN, collect)` should replace `as.call(c(FUN, collect))`*) for each combination of parameters. E.g.:

```
ff(list(param1 = c("a", "b"), param2 = c("A", "B")), c)
#$a
#$a$A
#.Primitive("c")(param1 = "a", param2 = "A")
#
#$a$B
#.Primitive("c")(param1 = "a", param2 = "B")
#
#
#$b
#$b$A
#.Primitive("c")(param1 = "b", param2 = "A")
#
#$b$B
#.Primitive("c")(param1 = "b", param2 = "B")
```

Comparing against the example:

```
b = ff(list(variable = c("A", "B", "C"), 
            model = c("m0", "m1"), 
            type = c("absolute", "relative")),
       paste)

b          #to see the object

identical(a, rapply(b, eval, how = "replace"))
#[1] TRUE

b$A$m0$absolute
#(function (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL) 
#.Internal(paste(list(...), sep, collapse)))(variable = "A", model = "m0", 
#    type = "absolute")
eval(b$A$m0$absolute)
#[1] "A m0 absolute"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want

```
variable <- c("A", "B", "C")
model <- c("m0", "m1")
type <- c("absolute", "relative")
cross3(variable, model, type) %>% 
    setNames(., map(., paste, collapse="_")) %>%
    map(paste, collapse=" ")
```

Which gives

```
#> $A_m0_absolute
#> [1] "A m0 absolute"
#> 
#> $B_m0_absolute
#> [1] "B m0 absolute"
#> 
#> $C_m0_absolute
#> [1] "C m0 absolute"
#> 
#> $A_m1_absolute
#> [1] "A m1 absolute"
#> 
#> $B_m1_absolute
#> [1] "B m1 absolute"
#> 
#> $C_m1_absolute
#> [1] "C m1 absolute"
#> 
#> $A_m0_relative
#> [1] "A m0 relative"
#> 
#> $B_m0_relative
#> [1] "B m0 relative"
#> 
#> $C_m0_relative
#> [1] "C m0 relative"
#> 
#> $A_m1_relative
#> [1] "A m1 relative"
#> 
#> $B_m1_relative
#> [1] "B m1 relative"
#> 
#> $C_m1_relative
#> [1] "C m1 relative"
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this gives a simple flat list, just like my `expand.grid + map` example (which gives a similar output although your answer better preserves the names). I stated clearly that I don't want to flatten the structure and want a list of lists (of lists of lists...) as output.