# How to create a list of unknown depth with variable names?

Tags: r, list

I want to create a list of unknown depth.

This is somehow related to my other question ([apply a function to a parameter grid and return a list of lists in purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355653/apply-a-function-to-a-parameter-grid-and-return-a-list-of-lists-in-purrr)) but I thought this may deserve its own post.

After some errings, I found that one can create such a list by writing this:

```
rtn = list()
rtn$a$f$t=6
rtn
```

This gives a list of depth 4 (according to `purrr:vec_depth(rtn)`), which is exactly the expected output.

> ```
> $a
> $a$f
> $a$f$t
> [1] 6
> ```

Unfortunately, when I tried to use names, `rtn[["a"]][["f"]][["t"]]="6"` did not work :

> ```
> $a
>   f 
> "6"
> ```

Here, `rtn` is a list with `rtn$a` being a simple vector, and the "t" index being dropped.

Reading `?Extract`, I noted there is a chapter about "Recursive (list-like) objects", which states a difference between `[[<-` and `$<-`:

> When `$<-` is applied to a `NULL` `x`, it first coerces `x` to `list()`. This is
>   what also happens with `[[<-` if the replacement value `value` is of
>   length greater than one: if `value` has length 1 or 0, `x` is first
>   coerced to a zero-length vector of the type of value.

**How could I construct such a list with variables?** (with base R or any `tidyverse`/`rlang` package, preferrably)

Here is my attempt so far:

**Disclaimer:** This might be one of the ugliest code I've ever written, with this operator reassignation (which did not totally work), but who knows, it may lead to something better...

```
`[[<-`=`$<-` #yuck...
rtn = list()
rtn$a$f$t=6
rtn[["a"]][["f"]][["t"]]="6" #this works!
xx="b"
rtn[[xx]][["f"]][["t"]]="6" #but this does not: unexpectedly it creates a level "xx" instead of "b"
rm(`[[<-`) #better safe than sorry
rtn
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` and `parse` to *create a list of unknown depth with variable names*.

```
rtn = list()
rtn$a$f$t  <- 6
rtn[[c("a","f","t")]] <- 7
xx="b"
eval(parse(text=paste0("rtn$",xx,"$f$t <- 8")))
rtn
#$a
#$a$f
#$a$f$t
#[1] 7

#$b
#$b$f
#$b$f$t
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach to such problems is to use a recursive function. One way is (*fully edited original post*):

```
ff = function(nms, val, init = list())
{
  if(!length(nms)) return(val)
  init[[nms[1]]] = c(init[[nms[1]]], ff(nms[-1], val))
  return(init)
}
```

Testing it while updating an existing list:

```
rtn = list()
rtn$a$f$t = 6
rtn$a$j$r = 19
rtn$b$r = 3
rtn$b$v$f$w = 42
rtn$c$e = 11

rtn2 = ff(c("a", "f", "t"), 6)
rtn2 = ff(c("a", "j", "r"), 19, rtn2)
rtn2 = ff(c("b", "r"), 3, rtn2)
rtn2 = ff(c("b", "v", "f", "w"), 42, rtn2)
rtn2 = ff(c("c", "e"), 11, rtn2)

identical(rtn, rtn2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is quite interesting and it may be useful sometimes, but I think it lacks flexibility. I can write `rtn$a$f$t=6; rtn$a$j$r=19` to update the list, but with this recursive function I can only write a single value.

Comment: @DanChaltiel : You're right about that; I ignored the case for updating an existing list. I made a quick edit; seems to be correct now unless I've missed something.